# Easy Twitter API PHP Question

Tags: xml, twitter, simplexml

This should be fairly easy, but I think I am being a bit stupid ....

I want to get the full_name from twitter:places - can anyone help me please?

To get the other elements I use $entry->title for example, but $entry->twitter:places->full_name doesnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns:google="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com/">
  <id></id>
  <link type="text/html" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=" rel="alternate"/>
  <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" rel="self"/>
  <title>Twitter Search</title>
  <link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/opensearch.xml" rel="search"/>
  <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?&amp;since_id=" rel="refresh"/>
  <updated>2011-06-01T18:32:50Z</updated>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>15</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
    <id></id>
    <published>2011-06-01T18:32:50Z</published>
    <link type="text/html" href="" rel="alternate"/>
    <title></title>
    <content type="html"></content>
    <updated>2011-06-01T18:32:50Z</updated>
    <link type="image/png" href="" rel="image"/>
    <twitter:geo>
    </twitter:geo>
    <twitter:metadata>
      <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
    </twitter:metadata>
    <twitter:place>
      <twitter:id></twitter:id>
      <twitter:full_name>London</twitter:full_name>
      <twitter:type>city</twitter:type>
    </twitter:place>
    <twitter:source></twitter:source>
    <twitter:lang>en</twitter:lang>
    <author>
      <name></name>
      <uri></uri>
    </author>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Can anyone help please!?

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the prefixed elements (which indicate a non-default namespace), you can filter by namespace:

```
$name = $xml->entry->children('http://api.twitter.com/')->place->full_name
```

or by bound prefix:

```
$name = $xml->entry->children('twitter', true)->place->full_name
```

Your other option would be to use XPath:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('t', 'http://api.twitter.com/');
$names = $xml->xpath('//t:full_name');
$name = $names[0];
```

If you want to use an exact XPath, it gets more complicated, since there are different namespaces in your path:

```
// Set up our own prefix for default namespace (we could also just use the Atom prefix explicitly as we do below with Twitter)
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('atom', $namespaces['']);
// Set up our own Twitter prefix
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('t', 'http://api.twitter.com/');
$names = $xml->xpath('/atom:feed/atom:entry/t:place/t:full_name'); 
$name = $names[0];
```

XML namespace prefixes are generally arbitrary--the important thing is the namespace (as indicated by our ability to bind whatever prefix we want in our code above).